# How to dodge a missile in Crash Team Racing Nitro Fueled?

Tags: crash-team-racing-nitro-fueled

Missiles can be relatively easily evaded by jumping slopes on tracks such as Tiny Arena. You also may be able to guide one into a wall by performing a sharp turn. Is there's any way to avoid being hit when on flat, open ground without items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can jump the missile when your timing is right ([seen here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h6UPy2j5pWk)). Look backwards when you get targeted to get a feel when to jump. With the lag in online this is nearly impossible to pull off.

If there are racers near you you can try to drive in front of them so the rocket will hit them and not you.

You already mentioned a sharp turn and this is also a good way. Just do a 360 by repeated jumping + dpad down + dpad left/right + holding brake which should be faster than getting hit and recovering, you won't even lose your reserves doing this.

Comment: I've suspected that this is possible as I've seen the AI characters performing this maneuver.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Only thing I can think of is guiding them into items already placed on the ground, but that probably isn't the answer you're looking for. But without any weird online hit registration issues, a missile fired in a flat and open area should hit you. I think if they didn't, they'd be unsatisfying to use and much weaker as the target would be able to avoid getting hit by them in almost every scenario.

Comment: The ability to dodge them wouldn't make it irrelevant.  Having to maneuver to avoid it would be a good enough reason to use it against someone.

Comment: True, but we're being pedantic over fantasy now. What if all you had to to do is hop to avoid it? I'd argue that would still make it pretty irrelevant. But irrelevant might be the wrong word, maybe "very under powered" if all it did was force people to manoeuvre, only when they're in giant open flat areas, and only when they're not going fast enough to get to the next bend in the track before it gets to them. At that point I'd rather just have the flexibility of the rolling bombs/beakers which are meant to be worse based on the placements you receive them at.

Comment: But what if you had to do something more elaborate than just hopping, like turn yourself approximately 90 degrees for half a second, then back, or something like that?  Just because they can be evaded it doesn't make them useless.  It's only irrelevant if dodging them were trivial, and since it's a hypothetical we wouldn't have to assume that.

Comment: Ok, again, maybe the use of "irrelevant" wasn't correct. But obviously I didn't mean they'd be completely 100% irrelevant, because whether you can dodge them or not, they'd still be able to hit people who are standing still for example. I was just trying to put emphasis on the fact that, the scenario the OP mentioned is where missiles are meant to shine and taking that away from them would make them very underwhelming and unsatisfying to use. I'll edit my answer for you.